# Can't run query in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've started this with only name and email field and query did run successfully, as it's working fine I added more fields updating the code. But this time it's not working, taking me to the same page not giving me any error.

```
<?php 

require "config.php";

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['postalcode']) && isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['datepicker']) && isset($_POST['phone'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $email = $_POST['email']; 
  $birthday = $_POST['datepicker'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  if(!empty($name) && !empty($address) && !empty($city) && !empty($postalcode) && !empty($country) && !empty($email) && !empty($birthday) && !empty($phone)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (name, address, city, postalcode, country, email, birthday, phone, IP, date) VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$city', '$postalcode', '$country', '$email', '$birthday' '$phone', '$IP', '$date')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

                 if($result) {
      echo "Registered Successfully";
    } else {
      echo "You're required to fill in all the fields.";
    }
  } 
}

 ?>

<form action="join.php" method="POST">

<p> <label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" > </p>

<p> <label for="address">Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="address" > </p>

<p> <label for="city">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="city" > </p>

<p> <label for="postalcode">Postal Code:</label>
<input type="text" name="postalcode" > </p>

<p> <label for="country">Country:</label>
<input type="text" name="country" > </p>

<p> <label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" > </p>

<p> <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
<input type="text" name="birthday" > </p>

<p> <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" > </p>

<input type="submit" value="order">

 </form>
```

I've pasted the code here: http://codepad.org/BuRFV276

Comment: Do use proper error reporting methods.

Comment: 1. check the database connection                                              2. echo your query; copy and execute on mysql will find errors easily

Comment: Let's only hope that `config.php` doesn't contain an `i`.

Comment: Obligatory plea to change to PDO or mysqli_ or some other method of connection to your database because mysql_ functions are deprecated. In addition you're set up to allow SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma here, between the `$birthday` and `$phone` variables-

```
'$birthday' '$phone',
//         ^ right there
```

Comment: Dear Questioner, This is the first answer that made. Voted. This is the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error.

But why is it giving me the same problem again if I add a new field in form and variable in query?

Comment: Make sure that you're using the needed commas.

Comment: If you're still getting an error @NewbieDeveloper update the code in your original post and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

you do not have any field named 'datepicker'.

Just replace all `$_POST['datepicker']` by `$_POST['birthday']`

and you have syntax error in insert query. You missed comma between $`birthday` and $`phone`

Do not use `mysql_*` since all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error.

But why is it giving me the same problem again if I add a new field in form and variable in query?